# Redirect to root url passing some data on response in node js

Tags: node.js, express

redirect to home url , by passing  some user details. The below code will redirect to root url and pass the username through url params.

```
 exports.successfull = (req,res) => {
      var userName = JSON.parse(req.body).username
      res.redirect("/?username="+ userName);
    }
```

so the expected url on client side  will be https://www.example.com/?username="John%20%Doe"

another way is

```
res.send({
  url: "/",
  data: {
   username: userName
  }
})
```

res.send doesn't redirect instead it will send the string which means here on the client side it will give "/".

but on the url there wont be any string params.

so without string params and using redirect how can i achieve the above. if i use res.send it will send the string, if i use res.redirect we need to append the params.

i just want to redirect and pass the data without showing the username on the url params

Do i need to use session , cookie,   or kind of anything?

Comment: Yes, that's what sessions are for.

Comment: thanks @robertklep

Comment: @robertklep how can i use the session properly here

Comment: That would require a tutorial on how to add session support to Express, which falls beyond the scope of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to think about this in a different way. You can call a setter on your express `app` instance and that will set a variable on `app` you can then retrieve later, but this will make your web server **stateful**. A stateful web server can be very buggy if you don't know what you are doing.

You can instead receive the data and render a template in the same POST request.

```
app.post('/getdata', function(req, res){
  res.render('/examplePage.SOMETEMPLATEENGINE', {
    data: req.body.username
  });
});
```

Or better yet you can use express sessions or cookies. Express sessions can be set up using [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) middleware and set up like so.

```
const session = require('express-session');

app.use(session({
    name: "my-session-name",
    secret: 'my-secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: // your prefered data store,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: oneDay
    }
}));
```

this will require the use of a `data store` as sessions store all of the end-users information on the database. If you would like a more simple approach as I take it you are a beginner, you could implement the data in a cookie using [cookie-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser). I recommend you read up on the docs. (don't worry it's not as hard as it may look)

A cookie implementation might look like this once you have your [cookie-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser) middleware set up.

```
app.post('/setdata', (req, res, next) => {
    // we will set a cookie here
    res.cookie('mycookie', {username: req.body.username})
   // this will set a cookie on the clients browser with whatever value you wan't
})
```

Now on every request, the client will automatically send this cookie to every route and
we can access it like this.

```
// future route the user visits
app.get('/showcookie', (req, res, next) => {
   // we can access the cookie we set if the user has visited the previous route like 
      //this
   let username = req.cookies.mycookie.username
   // and you can do with it what you wan't afterward
})
```

If you would like a super simple express app that shows you a working example of cookies here's a link to a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Bryce-Davidson/express-cookie-study) I wrote to show some of my friends how cookies work in express. I Hope this helps. It's always best to learn about what you're working with before moving on to something else especially when you are working with user data. Cheers.